# Is this anti-foundation axiom consistent?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Starting with ZFC:

- Replace axiom of Extensionality by weak Extensionality (nonempty sets having the same members, are identical)
- Remove axiom of Foundation.
- Add the anti-foundation axiom which states that: if $G$ is a graph such that there do NOT exist two distinct nodes $a,b$ of $G$ such that there exists edges of $G$ stemming from $a,b$ towards a common third node of $G$ that is distinct from $a,b$; then for every node $p$ of $G$ that reaches every other node of $G$ (i.e. for every node $n$ of $G$ other than $p$, there is a path of $G$ from $p$ to $n$); there is a set $p*$ such that the membership graph on $p*$ is isomorphic to $G$! That is: there is an isomorphic function $f$ from the transitive closure of $\{p*\}$ to the set of all nodes of $G$ such that $f(p*)=p$ and for every elements $a,b$ of the transitive closure of $\{p*\}$ we have: $$ b \in a \leftrightarrow \langle f(a) , f(b) \rangle \in G$$

A graph here can be captured by being a set of ordered pairs, a node of a graph is a projection of an element of that graph, an edge of $G$ from $a$ to $b$ can be defined as $\langle a,b \rangle \in G$, and a path of $G$ from $a$ to $b$ is defined as a subset of $G$ satisfying the usual definition of a directed finite path from $a$ to $b$.

Of course this clearly violates Aczel's anti-foundation axiom!

> My question: Is the resulting theory consistent? and if so, then would that be a kind of maximal anti-foundation axiom that is compatible with weak Extensionality in the milieu of *weakly extensional ZFC-Foundation*?

Comment: What suggests that this would be consistent? Have you tried proving the negation?

Comment: I tried of course, yet I failed. However, I think there would be problem with Extensionality even with the weak form, but a part from that I think it would work, because the buildup of the transitive closures of added sets only copies the structure of already existing graphs.